# No response from FTP with PhpStorm

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I can't connect to FTP server with PhpStorm Deployment. Similarly, I am not experiencing any issues connecting with FileZilla or VSCode (ftp-simple extension). There are some logs:

```
2023-02-24 02:22:03,691 [ 136847]   FINE - #c.j.p.w.c.RemoteConnection - Opening connection to ftp://%host%:21/ in @1dd6f261
2023-02-24 02:22:03,744 [ 136900]   FINE - #c.j.p.w.c.s.SocketWrapper - Default socket connection to %host%/88.99.160.97:21 60000
2023-02-24 02:22:03,791 [ 136947]   WARN - #c.j.p.w.c.RemoteConnection - Retrying connecting to ftp://%host%:21/ in @1dd6f261: 1 iterations
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Unknown message with code "Could not connect to FTP server on "%host%".".
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.PatchedFtpFileSystem.getClient(PatchedFtpFileSystem.java:109)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doGetChildren(FtpFileObject.java:103)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.doListChildren(FtpFileObject.java:355)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:1043)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileObject.getChildren(FtpFileObject.java:343)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChild(AbstractFileObject.java:984)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.RemoteConnectionPool.lambda$createConnection$0(RemoteConnectionPool.java:255)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to FTP server on "%host%".
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpClientFactory$ConnectionFactory.createConnection(FtpClientFactory.java:230)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpClientFactory.createConnection(FtpClientFactory.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.createClient(FTPClientWrapper.java:77)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.createClient(FTPClientWrapper.java:70)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.getFtpClient(FTPClientWrapper.java:82)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FTPClientWrapper.<init>(FTPClientWrapper.java:52)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpFileSystem.createWrapper(FtpFileSystem.java:117)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.PatchedFtpFileSystem.access$000(PatchedFtpFileSystem.java:21)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.PatchedFtpFileSystem$FtpClientFactory.create(PatchedFtpFileSystem.java:29)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.PatchedFtpFileSystem$FtpClientFactory.create(PatchedFtpFileSystem.java:22)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:899)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:429)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:354)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.connections.PatchedFtpFileSystem.getClient(PatchedFtpFileSystem.java:106)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.config.sockets.SocketWrapper.connect(SocketWrapper.java:50)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:253)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.ftp.FtpClientFactory$ConnectionFactory.createConnection(FtpClientFactory.java:169)
    ... 30 more
2023-02-24 02:22:12,827 [ 145983]   FINE - #c.j.p.w.c.s.SocketWrapper - Default socket connection to %host%/88.99.160.97:21 60000
2023-02-24 02:22:14,876 [ 148032]   WARN - #c.j.p.w.c.RemoteConnection - Connection cancelled to ftp://%host%:21/ in @1dd6f261
2023-02-24 02:22:15,605 [ 148761]   INFO - #c.i.j.JdkEx - === TabbingMode: disabled (true,true,true,true) ===
2023-02-24 02:22:15,609 [ 148765]   INFO - #c.i.j.JdkEx - === TabbingMode: disabled (true,true,true,true) ===
2023-02-24 02:23:07,667 [ 200823]   WARN - #c.j.p.w.c.RemoteConnection - Forced closing file system of ftp://%host%:21/ in @1dd6f261
2023-02-24 02:23:07,675 [ 200831]   FINE - #c.j.p.w.c.RemoteConnection - File system of ftp://%host%:21/ in @1dd6f261 is closed.
```

I have tried changing the deployment configuration in different ways.

Comment: Is your firewall blocking port 21?

Comment: my firewall is off

Comment: What happens when you `ping 88.99.160.97`?

Comment: It's sending packages

Comment: Verify that the port is correct. If so, try setting the FTP connection to passive mode. Beyond that, I'm not sure what the problem could be. Bad login credentials perhaps?

Comment: It looks like the server rejects the connection. What would happen if you telnet the host with `telnet 88.99.160.97 21`?